# Trying to understand the Matlab's patch command

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I don't understand why the patch command fill with red the area above my function instead of the area below it; I mean the area between the graph of my function and the axis of abscissas.

```
x = linspace(0, 4);
f = x.^2;
plot(x, f)
patch(x, f, [1 0 0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `patch` draws a closed polygon. And after your last point it goes back to the first on the shortest way. You need to add an additional points at the end and beginning with the last/first argument, but `f = 0`.

Like that:

```
x = linspace(0, 4);
f = x.^2;

plot(x, f)

%adjust data

x = [x(1) x x(end)];
f = [0 f 0];

patch(x, f, [1 0 0])
```

will give:

[image]

Or just use `area` as suggested by Luis Mendo:

```
area(x, f,'FaceColor',[1 0 0])
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you can use `area(x, f)` with the original values